# How to detect tabs in PDFs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pdf, docx

For example, say i want to extract all the clauses from this PDF, into individual excel cells for example.
[Example PDF with clauses/tabs](https://www.standardsforhighways.co.uk/dmrb/search/2b5901c6-3477-4826-b780-cf99003fb5e0)

If i can detect every time there is a tab i.e. the space between the clause number and the text, shown in the image, I think this will detect the start of every clause in the PDF, and i could just extract all the text between the start of clauses.

[image]

I've tried python pdf readers, i've tried converting the pdf to a word document and then using python docx readers. I haven't been able to consistently detect the tabs that are so clear in the PDF though.
Anyone know how i could do this?

Comment: I'd recommend asking how to do this, rather than just asking if it's possible. And asking "where do I start" is a really broad question too that also might not be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Okay, sure, i've reworded my question slightly^ Do you think i should be posting this on a different site then?

Comment: That definitely could help, it's more clear what you're asking now. I think this is the right site but you're never guaranteed 100% to get a response. If you don't get one, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: There are no "tabs" in a PDF. That is a word processor concept. There is only spatial (x,y) information.

Comment: ah, okay. Do you know how i could extract this spatial information?